# Jupyter lab is not printing all parameters form sklearn model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've been using jupyter lab for several month and every time I run a sklearn model the output is like this:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", max_depth = 4)
clf
```

Which in the past showed this output:

```
DecisionTreeClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None, criterion='entropy',
                      max_depth=4, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                      min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                      min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                      min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort='deprecated',
                      random_state=None, splitter='best')
```

But now it only shows the params that I have actually set:

```
DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=4)
```

Anyone knows how to make Jupyter show the complete list of params again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the new feature called `print_only_changed` in the version 0.23. So don't roll down to previous version, just set the `print_only_changed` option as `False`.

```py
from sklearn import set_config
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", max_depth = 4)

set_config(print_changed_only=True)
clf 
# DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=4)

set_config(print_changed_only=False)
clf 
# DecisionTreeClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None, criterion='entropy',
#                        max_depth=4, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
#                        min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
#                        min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
#                        min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort='deprecated',
#                        random_state=None, splitter='best')
```

Comment: Is that configuration permanent? Or do I need to do it in every notebook?

Comment: default value is `False`. If you need the otherway, I have to set it every time.

Answer (score 4):

Other than downgrading `sklearn` or editing the source code, I would say you can just use:

```
clf.get_params()
```

```
{'ccp_alpha': 0.0,
 'class_weight': None,
 'criterion': 'gini',
 'max_depth': None,
 'max_features': None,
 'max_leaf_nodes': None,
 'min_impurity_decrease': 0.0,
 'min_impurity_split': None,
 'min_samples_leaf': 1,
 'min_samples_split': 2,
 'min_weight_fraction_leaf': 0.0,
 'presort': 'deprecated',
 'random_state': 0,
 'splitter': 'best'}
```

See the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.get_params).